# How to solve argument error in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I am using Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 3.2.16.  I am reading chapter 10 from Rails tutorial by Michael hartl.

When I run `bundle exec rspec spec/` then I got following error:

```
/home/james/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@rails3/gems/activemodel-3.2.16/lib/active_model/validations/validates.rb:86:in `validates': You need to supply at least one validation (ArgumentError)

from /home/james/rails3.2/rails_projects/sample_app/app/models/micropost.rb:7:in `<class:Micropost>'
```

My micropost.rb file

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content

  belongs_to :user

  validates :content, presence: true, length: { maximum: 140 }
  validates :user_id

  default_scope order: 'microposts.created_at DESC'
end
```

How could I solve this error?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error itself giving clue to solve this error.

In your micropost.rb file, add `presence: true` code just after `validates :user_id`.

Your updated **micropost.rb** file look like as follow:

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content

  belongs_to :user

  validates :content, presence: true, length: { maximum: 140 }
  validates :user_id, presence: true

  default_scope order: 'microposts.created_at DESC'
end
```

I think this will solve your error.

Comment: Oh! I could not find it. It's very shame.